# CSS Border Not Showing Up - Is in chrome inspector but not window

Tags: css, border

I am trying to put a border on the bottom of my table rows and it isn't showing up, I have no idea why. The border property shows up in google chromes element inspector but not in the browser window. Any ideas??

```
table.sidebar
{
     *border-collapse: collapse; //IE7 and lower
     border-collapse: collapse;
     border-spacing: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     border: 1px solid grey;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
}
table.sidebar th:first-child
{
     background-color: #DCE2F1;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
     -khtml-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
     border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
     font: bold 13px arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #b5b5b5;
     color: #2a4982;
     padding-top: 5px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
}
table.sidebar tr
{
     border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
table.sidebar td 
{
     padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
}
table.sidebar td:last-child
{
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     -khtml-border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
     border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: can you add your html and perhaps a fiddle also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`border` property cannot be added to the `<tr>` element. You can implement the same by applying the `border-bottom` to the `<td>` tags.

```
table.sidebar td 
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
}
```